# It seems that I managed to enable "mousekeys" on my android. How do I disable it?

Tags: linux, vnc, mouse

I have a Samsung Galaxy Note 10.1. I am using it with the Apple Bluetooth Keyboard. From time to time, I use a VNC client (androidVNC or FreebVNC) to connect to different machines.

At some point I must have pushed some magical key combination on the keyboard, which enabled the "mousekeys" mode. Namely, the arrow buttons on the keyboard now control the mouse (in the VNC window) rather than act as arrow buttons.
It is not specific to the wireless keyboard. The "Hacker's keyboard" input method (which also has arrow keys) behaves identically.
It is not specific to the machine I am connecting to - it seems the key-to-mousemove translation is happening on the android side.

In all apps except for the VNC clients the arrow buttons work as expected. However, as the problem appears for both androidVNC and FreebVNC applications, it is obviously not a matter of misconfiguration of a particular VNC client. Rebooting does not help.

Hence the question - could it be that I managed to somehow enable the "mousekeys" mode for the android by pushing something? Is there a way to disable or at least to debug it? I have root access.

So far I managed to find out there is something fishy about [Linux+MouseKeys+VNC](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg-server/+bug/192508).